# Pronouns in Freud's Totem and Taboo

Tags: pronoun, personal-pronoun

**Question**

What is the reference of *der* and *seiner* as occurring in this passage from Freud's Totem and Taboo*; or, if the question cannot be answered to satisfaction, do we perhaps have a corrupted copy of the passage?

> Aus äußeren wie aus inneren Gründen wähle ich für diese Vergleichung jene Völkerstämme, die von den Ethnographen als die zurückgebliebensten, armseligsten Wilden beschrieben worden sind, die Ureinwohner{pl} des jüngsten Kontinents{m}, Australien{n}, **der** uns auch in **seiner** Fauna soviel Archaisches, anderswo Untergegangenes, bewahrt hat.

*Full text is found [here](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/37065/37065-h/37065-h.htm)

**My Thoughts**

I have marked the number or gender of potential antecedents.

On *der*. Since *Kontinents* is the only masculine, *der* presumably refers to it? However, wouldn't it be more natural to start the relative clause with *das* as referring to *Australien* since it is closer and more definite in meaning?

On *seiner*. I would have expected *seiner* to refer to the same thing that the relative pronoun did, but that seems impossible because *seiner* after a dative *in* would be a reference to a feminine noun. But the only feminine noun in the whole sentence is *Vergleichung*, which makes no sense. Vergleichung does not have fauna!

In sum I would have liked to see *das* and *seinem*.

I am beginning to think that I might have a bad copy of the text.

**Question Restated**

Please let me know if there is a way to make grammatical sense of the passage. If I have a bad copy, please let me know what the book says on a good copy.

Comment: Des Kontinents, der ... - kein Grund sich Sorgen zu machen. Die Einwohner Australiens, das ... wäre aber auch gegangen.

Comment: I don't get the problem. "Der" and "seiner" both refer to "Kontinent". They correspond to the capitalised words in the following: "the continent, WHICH with ITS fauna..."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both do indeed refer to *Kontinent*. The name *Australien* is only given as an additional explanation (grammatically an apposition, which is also why it is separated from the remainder of the sentence by commas).

Regarding *seiner*, you seem to misunderstand how it works. *Sein* behaves like an adjective and agrees in number, case and gender with the following noun: *sein Aussehen*, *seine Tierwelt*, *in seiner Fauna*, *mit seinen Augen*. It is the word *sein* itself that conveys a reference to an owner of masculine or neutral gender, in singular; otherwise, *ihr* would be used: *Die Ureinwohner der jüngsten Landmasse, die uns auch in ihrer Fauna soviel Archaisches bewahrt hat.*

Comment: Thank you. Yes. "Sein" (like "ein") would have to agree with what it modifies! Once in a while I am tripped up like this by what never gave me a problem before.  I almost want to delete the question as too stupid. I need an emoticon of someone crying...

Comment: @Catomic Note, that it is perfectly acceptable to write the sentence as ‘die Ureinwohner Australiens, des jüngsten Kontinents, **das** uns auch in **seiner** Fauna …’ This would assume *Australia* to be more known than the fact that it is the ‘youngest’ continent. To Freud’s time, it is understandable that maybe not everybody had heard of Australia yet.